# The tangent at P passes through the origin. Find P

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The graph of 
$$
y=9-​(x-​4)^2
$$
is given.

[This is the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycfBj.png)

Comment: Any thoughts on this particular question?

Answer (score 0):

The tangent has the equation $\;y=ax$ since it passes through the origin. It intersects the parabola in a double point. Thus, the discriminant of the following equation must be zero.

$$ax=9-(4-x)^2 \iff x^2+(a-8)x+7=0$$

$$\Delta=a^2-16a+36=0$$

which gives two solutions:

$$a=8\pm2\sqrt{7}.$$
and

$$P=\pm\sqrt{7}(1,a).$$